# How to get Position of Dynamically added check Boxes and Radio Buttons as Listview items child position?

Tags: android, getview

How can you

1. Add a `CheckBox` dynamically in `getView()`?
2. set Text for `CheckBox`es with different counts...

   In explanation...

In a Listview

- Question 1 needs 5 check boxes
- Question 2 needs 7 check boxes
- Question 3 needs 3 check boxes
- Question 4 needs 8 check boxes

This is what i want and i used the code...

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.question_items, null);
            final TextView question_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qno_text);
            final TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qstn_text);
            LinearLayout linear_layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_vertical);

            question_number.setText(question_items.get(position).getQuestionNo());
            question.setText(question_items.get(position).getQuestion());
            String single_or_multiple = question_items.get(position).getSingleSelect();

    if(single_or_multiple.equals("0")) {

        final ArrayList<String> answer_check_box = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> questions_in_ques_and_ans = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> questions_and_checking = new ArrayList<>();

        checkBoxState = new boolean[question_items.get(position).getOptionList().size()];
        final int check_size = question_items.get(position).getOptionList().size();
        Log.d("Size", String.valueOf(check_size));

        for(int i = 0; i<question_items.get(position).getOptionList().size(); i++) {

            check_box = new CheckBox(context);
            check_box.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            check_box.setBackgroundDrawable(getApplication().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fifth_username));
            check_box.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            check_box.setText(question_items.get(position).getOptionList().get(i).getOPTIONS());
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            check_box.setLayoutParams(params);
            check_box.setId(i);
            check_box.setTag(i);
            check_box.setChecked(false);

            check_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int id = buttonView.getId();
                    Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(id));

                    tag_val = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                    String tag_value = String.valueOf(tag_val);
                    Log.d("TAG", tag_value);

                    Question_Number = question_number.getText().toString();
                    Question = question.getText().toString();
                    String value = "";
                            if(isChecked) {
                                value = question_items.get(position).getOptionList().get(id).getOPTIONS();
                                    Log.d("checkbox checked value", value);
                                answer_check_box.add(value);
                                if(questions.size() > 0) {
                                            if(questions.contains(Question)) {
                                                questions.remove(Question);
                                                questions.add(Question);
                                                } else {
                                                    questions.add(Question);
                                                }
                                        } else {
                                            questions.add(Question);
                                        }
                                Log.d("Answers Checked", answer_check_box.toString());
                                Log.d("Question Checked", questions.toString());
                                Answer = answer_check_box.toString();
                                    }else {
                                value = question_items.get(position).getOptionList().get(id).getOPTIONS();
                                Log.d("checkbox Unchecked value", value);
                                    answer_check_box.remove(value);
                                    if(answer_check_box.size() > 0) {
                                            } else {
                                            questions.remove(Question);
                                        }

                                Log.d("Answers Unchecked", answer_check_box.toString());
                                Log.d("Question UnChecked", questions.toString());
                                Answer = answer_check_box.toString();
                                      }

                            if(questions_and_checking.size() > 0) {
                                Log.d("Size","above 1");

                                for(int check = 0; check < questions_and_checking.size(); check++) {
                                    questions_in_ques_and_ans.add(questions_and_checking.get(check));
                                        }
                                Log.d("Questions check", questions_in_ques_and_ans.toString());
                                Log.d("Que array", ques_and_ans.toString());

                                if(questions_in_ques_and_ans.contains(Question)) {

                                    Log.d("Contains","Que");
                                    int index = ques_and_ans.indexOf(ques_and_ans.get(position));
                                    Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(index));
                                    ques_and_ans.remove(index);

                                    Question_and_Answer item = new Question_and_Answer();
                                    item.setQustionNumber(Question_Number);
                                    item.setQuestionTitle(Question);
                                    item.setOptionValue(Answer);
                                    ques_and_ans.add(item);
                                    questions_and_checking.add(Question);

                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("Not Contains","Que");
                                        Question_and_Answer item = new Question_and_Answer();
                                        item.setQustionNumber(Question_Number);
                                        item.setQuestionTitle(Question);
                                        item.setOptionValue(Answer);
                                        ques_and_ans.add(item);
                                        questions_and_checking.add(Question);
                                        }
                             } else {
                                 Log.d("Size", "0");
                                    Question_and_Answer item = new Question_and_Answer();
                                    item.setQustionNumber(Question_Number);
                                    item.setQuestionTitle(Question);
                                    item.setOptionValue(Answer);
                                    ques_and_ans.add(item);
                                    questions_and_checking.add(Question);
                                 Log.d("Check After First add", ques_and_ans.toString());
                               }
                            }
                        });
            linear_layout.addView(check_box);
            }


        } else {
                    radio_group = new RadioGroup(context);
                for(int i=0; i<question_items.get(position).getOptionList().size(); i++) {
                    radio_button = new RadioButton(context);
                    radio_button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    radio_button.setBackgroundDrawable(getApplication().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fifth_username));
                    radio_button.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                    radio_button.setText(question_items.get(position).getOptionList().get(i).getOPTIONS());
                    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    radio_button.setLayoutParams(params);
                    radio_group.addView(radio_button);
                            }
                linear_layout.addView(radio_group);

                radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rgp, int checkedId) {
                        Question_Number =question_number.getText().toString();
                        Question = question.getText().toString();

                        radioButtonID = radio_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        View radioButton = radio_group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                        idx = radio_group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                        Log.d("id", String.valueOf(idx));

                        String answer = question_items.get(position).getOptionList().get(idx).getOPTIONS();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, 2).show();
                        Answer = answer;

                        Question_and_Answer item = new Question_and_Answer();
                        item.setQustionNumber(Question_Number);
                        Log.d("Q_no", Question_Number);
                        item.setQuestionTitle(Question);
                        Log.d("Qstn", Question);
                        item.setOptionValue(Answer);
                        Log.d("Answer", Answer);
                        ques_and_ans.add(item);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    return view;
                        }
```

I cant able to get the check boxes and radio buttons positions... Because when i scroll it has unchecked automatically. I know it is the property of getView, but how can i control it with this code...

Comment: Here i used Textview, But i will change it check box later.

Comment: If you always have 4 questions just use a ScrollView.

Comment: No Mr.Jawad i had "n" no of questions.... But options count for the questions are different.

Comment: If you know the maximum number of checkboxes in each row. Add the maximum number in your xml layout with View property set to gone. And then you can make them visible or gone a t will to suit your needs.

Comment: yes Mr. Jawad. Your approach is correct if i know the checkbox count. But in this situation i have added 5th Question with 10 check boxes means, i cant able to populate 5th questions 9th, 10th options...

Answer (score 0):

> set Text for `CheckBoxes` with different counts?

Each `CheckBox` has a [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))-Function which you can call with the desired text.

> Add a `CheckBox` dynamically in getView?

Your `ViewHolder` contains a `LinearLayout`. Assuming you want to populate that with `CheckBox`es, you should be able to

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
cb.setText("some text");
linear_layout.addView(cb);
```

for each `CheckBox` you desire to add. You might also want to [set a onCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) to be notified when the user checks the `CheckBox`.

Maybe there is an easier approach than adding those elements in `getView()`?

> But the problem is convert view not works. Because My third and fourth
>   questions has 3 and 8 options respectively. But it shows only 5
>   options...

Assuming the number of checkboxes are in `question_items.get(position).getQuestionNo()`, 
you should be able to do

```
for ( int i = 0; i < question_items.get(position).getQuestionNo(); i++ ) {
    //code to add a single checkbox
}
```

and if you want to follow [@Jawad's approach about setting the visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438792/dynamically-add-check-box-in-listview-within-getview-for-different-data-counts#comment54667146_33438792), you could do that in the loop as well.

Comment: Yes user. I dont the thing instead od Textview above. But the problem is convert view not works. Because My third and fourth questions has 3 and 8 options respectively. But it shows only 5 options...

Comment: I think with that approach, if you have a question with less checkboxs than what was in the previous convertView, you will need to delete them because of view recycling.